# how to transform a string in a variable name ? python

Tags: python, string, variables, variable-names

how can I transform a string in a variable name ?
I have multiple variable value1, value2, value3 and value1 = 5
when i use

`x = 1 
print(str("value" + str(x)))`

it return "value1" and not "5"

**edit:**  it isn't a duplicate because i am asking how to solve my problem and not if it is good or bad to use eval(it is the link which you referred me to)

so when i use eval to change the value of the variable it doesn't work ("can't assign to function call"),

`global('newValue' + str(z))
eval('newValue' + str(z)) = y + value`

and if you do not recommend using eval what should you use instead ? because i have a lot of 'if value1 <' and 'if value 2 <' but i want to change it to a while

Comment: I would recommend you to use dictionaries. I believe it will be much better and comfortable for your case. Anyway, you can try something like this `exec("print(value" + str(x) + ")")` but it is awful practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(eval(str(“value” + str(x))))
```

But **must not** use `eval` even if you know it’s completely secure. There is always a better way.

Comment: And even then, you should still not use `eval` - there _are_ better solutions.

Comment: such as ? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Store these values in `list` or `dict`.

Comment: @l.b.dev in this case using a dict or a list or objects and `getattr` are the canonical solutions - "dynamic" variables are a terrible idea anyway.

Comment: I understand it but I have 15 lines of code "if value1 <" ,  "if value2 <" ,  "if value3 <" ,  "if value 15... with each time 10 lines of code in it but i need to have the value1 to have the value2 and so on. but i want to compress those 150 lines of code to avoid more code duplication. Also this code will apply to something like 10 000 first value that i need to change so it can't be done with a list or a dict because it would be to complicated to name all the value in the dict @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @l.b.dev if your code is such a mess then obviously you don't have the right data structure for the task at hand. Just a hint: python functions are objects too, so you can map indices to functions quite easily (that's just a list or tuple), and `zip` values and functions. Actually we have a perfect case of XY problem here - you ask about what you think is the solution instead of asking about your _real_ problem (the one you're trying to solve with this "solution").